# STU supergravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, supersymmetry, supergravity

Tghere are a lot of different papers about STU supergravity, for example [see this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.01957).

As I understand, STU supergravity is N = 2 supergravity coupled
to three vector multiplets.

**Could someone explain, what is the meaning of abbreviations "STU"?**

**Which properties of such theory motivate study it"s? Is such theory special in some sense?**

Comment: There are three $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ symmetries (S, T and U) inherited from its parent - M-theory on $T^7$. I guess one "motivation" behind it is seeing this STU triality between the low-energy limits of the triple (IIA on K3, IIB on K3, heterotic on $T^4$).